# Proving $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+z)=\cos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+z)=\cos(z)$$

My attempt using Euler identity:
$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+z)=\frac{e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+z)}-e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{2}-z)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-y}(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+x))-e^y(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{2}-x)+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{2}-x)))}{2i}=\frac{e^{-y}(-\sin(x)+i\cos(x))-e^y(-\sin(x)-i\cos(x)))}{2i}$

Now using $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ I get:

$\frac{e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-e^y(-\cos(x)+i\sin(x)))}{2}$

However the last expression does not equal the $\cos(z)$. I have checked many times but I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

**Question**:

What am I doing wrong on my proof? How should I correct it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the fact that $$e^{\pm i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+z\right)}=e^{\pm i\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{\pm i z}$$ in the second step, and recalling the values of $e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}},e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$?

Comment: Asking about a proof of such a simple relation one should always let know what is assumed to be known. For example: what is $\sin z$, what is $\cos z$, and finally the most interesting thing: what is $\pi $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier way, without separating the real and imaginary part of $z$.
Namely,
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+z\right) = \frac{1}{2i}\left( e^{i(\pi/2+z)} - e^{-i(\pi/2+z)} \right) = \frac{1}{2i} \left( ie^{iz} - (-i)e^{-iz} \right)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})=\cos z$$

We used the fact that $e^{i\pi/2} = i$.

Also, your proof thus far is correct, because the last expression you got is equal to

$$\frac{1}{2} (e^{-y+ix}+e^{y-ix}) = \frac{1}{2} \left(e^{i(x+iy)}+e^{-i(x+iy)}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}) = \cos z$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}=i$$